# First <th> as wide as possible with a maximum percentage width, with all the other <th> not wrapping

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th class="col one">One</th>
        <th class="col two">Two</th>
        <th class="col three">Three</th>
        <th class="col four">Four</th>
        <!-- Any number of columns follow... -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- content... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What is the correct way (with CSS) to style the columns so that they fit like this:

1. `col.one` has to stretch as much as possible, but not more than 35%.
2. all other columns can be as thin as possible, but without wrapping the content.

**Example**:

*Good*:

```
<-------------|   Max 35%   |-------------->
__________________________________________________________________
| One                                       | Two | Three | Four |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

*Bad*:

```
__________________________________________________________________
|                                                    | T | T | F |
|                                                    | w | h | o |
| One                                                | o | r | u |
|                                                    |   | e | r |
|                                                    |   | e |   |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `max-width:35%`

Answer (score 0):

For your first request, as @KheemaPandey said, you should use 
`max-width:35%`
 in CSS.

As per your second request, format the columns that you don't want to wrap with 
`white-space: nowrap;`.
 That should do it.

Comment: `max-width` %'s don't seem to work for me with columns in Chrome

Comment: w3schools says that it's supposed to work :[max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp)

Comment: `In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined.` and `Specifies a percentage for determining the used value. The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. If the containing block's width is negative, the used value is zero. If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.` according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths)